# Does Vault support two CA intermediates to sign two different environment certs?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

There are multiple non-production environments, such as DEV, TEST, QA, SIT, PKG, and if we want to manage a separate CA for each environment to sign certs, should we set up a separate vault cluster for each environment?

Is there any way that we can manage all these CA in the same vault cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create as many [PKI secrets engines](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/pki) as you like within a single vault cluster.

Rather than separate clusters (which would be a lot of overhead), create and mount PKI engines are separate mount points. eg: `pki/dev`, `pki/test`, etc... Each engine will hold the CA for the corresponding environment.

This applies to all secrets engines: Vault is happy to have more than one mounted, and all operations are on a specific path. You can of course apply separate policies to those engines.